# Nodejs: How to use async/await when trying to rate limit number of requests to the server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to use the geocode API to get the json object by limiting the number of requests to 1 per second. I need to use async/await and this is what I have

```
const requester = {
    lastRequest: new Date(),
    makeRequest: async (url) => {
        var timestart = new Date()
        // first check when last request was made
        var timeSinceLast = (timestart).getTime() - this.lastRequest.getTime();
        if (timeSinceLast < 1000) {
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, timeSinceLast));
        }
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const json = await response.json();
        return json;
        // make request here and return result
    }
};
var requestResponse = requester.makeRequest('https://geocode.xyz/?
     locate=Warsaw,Poland&json=1')
```

With this I am getting the following errors:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'getTime' of undefined
>
> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
>   error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
>   without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
>   with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)

I tried to find why this is happening and when just print the requester object, I don't get the gettime() undefined error. Am I using async/await and promises correctly? What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** Based on the answers below, I no longer see the error, however I see 'Request Throttled'

```
const requester = {
   lastRequest: new Date(),
   makeRequest: async function(url){
       var timestart = new Date()
       // first check when last request was made
       var timeSinceLast = (timestart).getTime() - this.lastRequest.getTime();
       if (timeSinceLast < 1000) {
           await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, timeSinceLast));
       }
       const response = await fetch(url);
       const json = await response.json();
       return json;
       // make request here and return result
   }
};
requester.makeRequest('https://geocode.xyz/?locate=Warsaw,Poland&json=1') 
.then(console.log)
```

This is what I am seeing now:

```
{ success: false,
 error: { code: '006', message: 'Request Throttled.' } }
```

Do I need to await for the response?

Comment: i think `this.lastRequest` should be `lastRequest`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Arrow functions don't have `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this), so `this.lastrequest.getTime` is `undefined`.

Use a normal function instead:

```js
const requester = {
    lastRequest: new Date(),
    makeRequest: async function(url){
        var timestart = new Date()
        // first check when last request was made
        var timeSinceLast = (timestart).getTime() - this.lastRequest.getTime();
        if (timeSinceLast < 1000) {
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, timeSinceLast));
        }
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const json = await response.json();
        return json;
        // make request here and return result
    }
};
requester.makeRequest('https://geocode.xyz/?locate=Warsaw,Poland&json=1') //Don't write strings in two lines
.then(console.log)
```

And if you add a `then(console.log)`, you can see the result!

Comment: Yes, The result is seen with success as false and message as request throttled. This shouldn't be seen right?

Comment: @Nikhil I think this isn't a promise error, this is the response from the website...

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `=>` arrow functions inside object methods as the `this` is not what you think it is.

The `this` within the arrow function is the one that was in the current context where you defined the object, in your case it is pointing to the global object which has no `lastRequest` property.

That is why `this.lastRequest` is evaluating to `undefined`.

You need to replace it with an anonymous function to correctly point to the `this.lastRequest` property.

Also you won't get the data you want by simply returning it from the object method and assigning it to a variable as the value returned from your method is wrapped in a promise (due to the `async` keyword) so you need to call `then` on it to actually capture the data from the service.

```js
const requester = {
    lastRequest: new Date(),
    makeRequest: async function(url) {
        var timestart = new Date();
        // first check when last request was made
        var timeSinceLast = timestart.getTime() - this.lastRequest.getTime();
        if (timeSinceLast < 1000) {
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, timeSinceLast));
        }
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const json = await response.json();
        return json; //wrapped in a promise
        // make request here and return result
    }
};
var requestResponse = requester.makeRequest('https://geocode.xyz/?locate=Warsaw,Poland&json=1').then((data)=>{
   console.log(data);
})
```

Some resources to look at:

[Arrow functions as object methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Arrow_functions_used_as_methods)

[Async function](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/async-functions)

Comment: Wow, I didn't know you could run the snippet. This solves the undefined error, however, I am now seeing promise pending error

Comment: @Nikhil check the last para of my answer, you shold call `then` to get the resolved  data because the returned value is a promise.

Comment: Tried the following. `requester.makeRequest('https://geocode.xyz/?locate=Warsaw,Poland&json=1') .then(console.log)` The promise pending error is no longer seen. However, I am not seeing the json output

Comment: Thanks, I still see the json output as request throttled. I thought I was rate-limiting to send 1 request per second.

Answer (score 1):

According to [geocode pricing options](https://geocode.xyz/pricing)

> Throttled API access is free. Rate limit: up to 1 API call per sec.  API (Throttled to no more that 1 request per second for all free port users combined. eg., if 2 free requests come at the same time, each gets throttled to 2 seconds per request).

SO this would mean that as a free user you don't have control whether the limit would be 1 second or something else.